# ifstream: how to tell if specified file doesn't exist

Tags: c++, file

I want to open a file for reading. However, in the context of this program, it's OK if the file doesn't exist, I just move on. I want to be able to identify when the error is "file not found" and when the error is otherwise. Otherwise means I need to quit and error.

I don't see an obvious way to do this with `fstream`.

---

I can do this with C's `open()` and `perror()`. I presumed that there was a `fstream` way to do this as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since the result of opening a file is OS-specific, I don't think standard C++ has any way to differentiate the various types of errors. The file either opens or it doesn't.

You can try opening the file for reading, and if it doesn't open (`ifstream::is_open()` returns `false`), you know it either doesn't exist or some other error happened. Then again, if you try to open it for writing afterwards and it fails, that might fall under the "something else" category.

Comment: Sure it's OS-specific, but if C can do it, why can't C++? C would set `errno` to `ENOENT` as distinct from `EACCESS` or other errors.

Comment: My answer was in relation to the standard C++ library. If you're calling OS-specific libraries that's not really C++ providing the feature. You're just calling OS-specific libraries from C++.

Comment: I was trying to say that there's room in a language for OS-agnostic ways of doing this (such as `fopen` from the C standard library). C++ may not currently expose such a thing, but there's no reason it *couldn't* or *shouldn't*. I was mostly responding to a vague sense of "this is the way it has to be" that I got from your answer's phrasing.

Answer (score 96):

EDIT: I've been notified that this does not necessarily indicate a file does not exist, as it may be flagged due to access permissions or other issues as well.

I know I'm extremely late in answering this, but I figured I'd leave a comment anyway for anyone browsing. You can use ifstream's fail indicator to tell if a file exists.

```
ifstream myFile("filename.txt");
    if(myFile.fail()){
        //File does not exist code here
    }
//otherwise, file exists
```

Comment: What you suggest is NOT a way to check for "file not found". `fail()` does not indicate "file does not exist", it just indicates "something is wrong". In your particular example it can be "access denied" or "sharing violation" etc.

Comment: Very good point, I didn't even consider that. I'll modify the response so that people are aware.

Answer (score 48):

I don't think you can know if "the file doesn't exist". You could use is_open() for generic checking:

```
ofstream file(....);
if(!file.is_open())
{
  // error! maybe the file doesn't exist.
}
```

If you are using `boost` you could use `boost::filesystem`:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path myfile("test.dat");

    if( !boost::filesystem::exists(myfile) )
    {
        // what do you want to do if the file doesn't exist 
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not ofstream but ifstream!

Comment: Note that both ways check something else: the file may well be there but you might not have the necessary permissions...

Comment: Isn't this an inherently racy solution?

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c) thread, there's also the `file.good()` option, which I think is more appropriate here.

Comment: `boost::filesystem::exists` has been added in C++17 as [`std::filesystem::exists`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

Answer (score 10):

A simple way from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1796/

```
ifstream ifile(filename);
if (ifile) {
  // The file exists, and is open for input
}
```

Comment: in case anyone else is wondering: [According to the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), this is identical to `!ifile.fail()`. `if(!ifile)` is equivalent to `ifile.fail()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use stat, which should be portable across platforms and is in the standard C library:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

bool FileExists(string filename) {
    struct stat fileInfo;
    return stat(filename.c_str(), &fileInfo) == 0;
}
```

If stat returns 0, the file (or directory) exists, otherwise it doesn't.  I assume that you'll have to have access permissions on all directories in the file's path.  I haven't tested portability, but [this page](http://www.techbytes.ca/techbyte103.html) suggests it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Should explictly check return code, as it may be non-zero for reasons other than file doesn't exist. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html

Comment: This is a WRONG thing to do, because during the time AFTER stat() returned and BEFORE `fstream`'s open() got to actually opening a file the file may have been already gone (deleted by another process in the system).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c

Answer (score 4):

A better way:

```
std::ifstream stream;
stream.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
stream.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: Please add some explaination/[references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

With C++17 you can use [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!fs::exists(fileName))
{
     // error! file doesn't exist.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's me give example with real running:

1. file does't exist:

[image]

2. file exist:

[image]

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ for more information about its public function.

Comment: This doesn't account for the possibility that the file actually exists but there is an error in accessing it, like permission denied, I/O errors, etc

Answer (score -6):

Straight way without creating ifstream object.

```
if (!std::ifstream(filename))
{
     // error! file doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: This creates an `ifstream` object, just one that goes out of scope as soon as the `if` statement is finished