# If file exist, work with it, if no, create it

Tags: c++, file, fstream

```
fstream datoteka;
datoteka.open("Informacije.txt",  fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);

if(!datoteka.is_open()){              
    ifstream datoteka("Informacije.txt")
    datoteka.open("my_file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
}/*I'm writing IN the file outside of that if statement.
```

So what it should do is create a file if it was not created before, and if it is created write into that file.

Hello there, so what I wanted from my program is that it check if the file already exists, sothe program open if it does and I can write in it, if the file is not opened(**have not been created before**) the program create it. So the problem is when I create a .csv file, and finish writing and I wanted to check if the written is really there, the file cannot be opened. In .txt file, everything is blank.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c.

Comment: When you're done with the `datoteka` in the if-block the file is closed. The original outside the if-block was never opened, so anything you're do to *that* doesn't actually "do" **anything**. (I can only imagine the unchecked IO you didn't post) What is the point of the `datoteka` in the if-block anyway?

Answer (score 13):

`datoteka.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);`
    works fine.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

     char filename[ ] = "Informacije.txt";
     fstream appendFileToWorkWith;

     appendFileToWorkWith.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);


      // If file does not exist, Create new file
      if (!appendFileToWorkWith ) 
      {
        cout << "Cannot open file, file does not exist. Creating new file..";

        appendFileToWorkWith.open(filename,  fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
        appendFileToWorkWith <<"\n";
        appendFileToWorkWith.close();

       } 
      else   
      {    // use existing file
         cout<<"success "<<filename <<" found. \n";
         cout<<"\nAppending writing and working with existing file"<<"\n---\n";

         appendFileToWorkWith << "Appending writing and working with existing file"<<"\n---\n";
         appendFileToWorkWith.close();
         cout<<"\n";

    }




   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise,
the fstream::app, If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.

```
int writeOnfile (char* filetext) {
       ofstream myfile;
       myfile.open ("checkSellExit_file_output.csv", fstream::app);
       myfile << filetext;
       myfile.close();
       return 0;
    }
```