# How to check if a file exists in C++ with fstream::open()

Tags: c++

I'm using fstream library to work with files. Basically, I need to know if a certain file exists or not. In c++ documentation online, about open(), it reads:

> Return Value
>
> none
>
> If the function fails to open a file, the failbit state flag is set
>   for the stream (which may throw ios_base::failure if that state flag
>   was registered using member exceptions).

It says not return value is specified. But in case of failure, a flag is set. My question is that, I should I then access that flag, or to better ask, how should I see if `open()` is successful or not.

I have this code so far:

```
int Log::add()
{
    fstream fileStream;

    fileStream.open("logs.txt");
}
```

Comment: `fileStream.is_open()`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open

Comment: Then what about flags and exception in case of failure? is_open is used immediately after the open() regularly?

Comment: C++ is rather bad in that field. There are two flags: `fail` and `bad` which can be tested, but it does not tell you whether the file was protected or did not exist or the path was wrong...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It says it sets the failbit if the file couldn't be opened. So you can check for that bit:

```
fileStream.open("logs.txt");
if (fileStream.fail()) {
    // file could not be opened
}
```

Actually, just `if (fileStream)` would work here as well, since `ios` (a base class of `ifstream`, `ofstream`, and `fstream`) has a conversion operator to `bool`.

Don't worry about the failure exception. You can request exceptions to be thrown on failure by calling `ios::exceptions` but by default exceptions are not thrown on failure.

Note that this doesn't tell you *why* the file couldn't be opened. It could be that the file didn't exist, that a directory in the path didn't exist, you don't have permission to open the file, your program has reached the limit on the number of files it can open, and so on. There is no portable way to determine the reason.

Comment: Note that it is safer to use `is_open()`. The bad and fail bits are not always reset properly between calls, at least in my experience...

Comment: also note `.good()` which would indicate all three of `eofbit` `failbit` and `badbit` are not set, which would catch EOF condition as well.

Answer (score 11):

Your method doesn't check for existence, but rather accessibility. It is possible to check existence like this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

inline bool exists (const std::string& filename) {
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat (filename.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
}
```

In C++14 it is possible to use this:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

bool exist = std::experimental::filesystem::exists(filename);
```

& in C++17: ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists))

```
#include <filesystem>

bool exist = std::filesystem::exists(filename);
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that there are difference between "File exist" and "File can be opened".

To check if file exist (and you indeed do not need to open/read/write the file), use `fstat` or its c++ counterpart - you don't need any permission to query the info.

Note that if you want to check file exist before open it, you are doing it wrong. Condition may have changed between your checking and the actual attempt to open the file. In general, you just directly open the file with the open/creation options without previously checking.

Comment: What is "its c++ counterpart"?

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods `is_open`, `fail`, for example:

```
string path = "not_exists.txt";
ifstream fin(path);

if(fin.is_open()){
    cout<<"file is open"<<endl;
} else{
    cout<<"file isn't open"<<endl;
}

if(fin.fail()){
    cout<<"file open fail"<<endl;
} else{
    cout<<"file open success"<<endl;
}
```

output as below:

[image]

[image]

See: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/  for reference.