# Is there a good C++ library for manipulating files and directories, other than Boost's filesystem?

Tags: c++, libraries, directory-structure

I've been having a heck of a time trying to link `filesystem` into my program on my `Unix` machine and so I'm going to give up and try another library if a good one exists. Come to think of it, the only functionalities I need are:

(1) Verifying the existence of a folder by its full path given by a user in the command line

(2) Checking whether a filename/extension combination exists in a directory given by a user in the command line

Can I get that from the standard library?

Comment: For existence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c. Keep in mind that C++ is almost guaranteed to have a standard filesystem library within a few years.

Comment: Can you possibly quantify/qualify your notion of "good"? And mention what platform you're working on? For systems that are Posix compliant, `stat()` or `access()` or other related calls should be sufficient for your two stated requirements, without the use of additional libraries...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Qt. Great file handling classes.

http://qt-project.org/

QFile and QDir are a good place to start.