# C++ Change output file name if exists

Tags: html, c++, output, ostream

I'm trying to write HTML output file. The file is written and all is well, but I'd like to know if there is a way to take a string with it's file name, check if that exists and if yes then change that string somehow. So I would never overwrite already existing file.

```
string outputFile;
cin>>outputFile;
ofstream out;
string path ="..\\data\\"+ outputFile+ ".html";
out.open(path.c_str());
```

So in this case if outputFile is let's say "Jesus" then I want to do something so if I would run this 3 times I'd have something like Jesus.html, Jesus2.html, Jesus3.html. Doesn't necesarilly have to be numbered like that, just any change to that string will do. Is this even possible? I tried this using 
`tmpnam()` 
but I don't really understand how it's supposed to work and if it can even be used.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

you could check if the file exists with one of the methods mentioned here:

[Fastest way to check if a file exist using standard C++/C++11/C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c#12774387)

The complete code would look like this

```
inline bool file_exists (const std::string& name) {
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
}

while (file_exists(file_name))
    file_name += "_1";
```