# c++ assert error C2120: 'void' illegal with all types

Tags: c++

Error after compiling in visual studio (C2120: 'void' illegal with all types). New to c++, basically trying to make the program return an error if the file they enter does not exist. Any advice would help. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string input_file_name;
    cout << "Give name of input file : ";
    cin >> input_file_name;
    ifstream ins(input_file_name.c_str());
    assert(ins);

    if (assert(ins) == false)
        cout << "Error: " << input_file_name << "does not exist";
}
```

Comment: More to the point, what are you trying to accomplish with `if (assert(ins) == false)` in the first place? I'm pretty sure you're wanting `if (!ins.is_open())`. And fyi, not-exist is only one of the cases where open-for-read can fail; there are others, so that error message is somewhat presumptive.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes that was what I was trying to accomplish. If you don't mind what other ways can errors occur? Also when I run the new code the cout error message does not execute. After an error I get an, assertion failed/abort() has been called error. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is always the old fashion test: `if (!ins) { /* perform error handling */ }`.  There is more than one way that an open can fail.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `assert` macro is `void assert (int expression);` as in [C++ assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/), thus you should not compare its return value.

Additionally, there are some ways you can accomplish some of your goals:

- [Fastest way to check if a file exist using standard C++/C++11/C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12774387/3155810)

Comment: `assert` is not a function, it is a macro.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: ok, nevermind. It is required to be a void expression, but it is still not true that it does implicit conversion to `int` in its argument or that the argument has to have type `int`. It only has to have any scalar type.