# Stop ofstream from creating a file

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying open a file and check if it exists yet it creates a new file if the given file does not exist. If it is going to automatically create a file, what's the point of the isOpen() then?

```
int main() {
std::ofstream defaultFile;
defaultFile.open("AAAAA.txt");
std::cout << defaultFile.is_open();//this will always print out "1"
}
```

Comment: `defaultFile.open()` will create a file if it doesn't exist, because `defaultFile` is an output stream.  If it succeeds in opening the file (whether it created that file or not) then `defaultFile.is_open()` will return true.     Try opening it as an *input* stream - opening will then fail if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the point of the isOpen() then?

Creating a file can fail for numerous reasons. One could be that you have no write access in the directory where you try to create the file. In that case

```
defaultFile.open("AAAAA.txt");
```

will fail and `is_open` will return `false`. If you want to know if the file exists before creating it you can do for example this:

```
ifstream f(name);
bool exits_and_can_be_opened = f.good();
```

Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12774387/4117728, but note that since C++17 there is the [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) with more straightforward ways to query properties of files.