# How to check if a file was deleted from a certain folder? (C++ 17)

Tags: c++, c++17

So I've been trying to make a program that detects file deletions, Lets say you delete a file from your desktop it will flag the name and the directory it will delete it from. Im trying to find a way to detect files deleted from prefetch or anything like that any solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774207/2754510

Comment: Really appreciate it!