# Check for file existence in C++ without creating file

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

I want to check if a file exists and tried to use the following function

```
#include <fstream>

bool DoesFileExist(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream ifile(filename.c_str());
    return (bool)ifile;
    }
```

However, it does not seem to work properly, because instead of checking the existence a file is created! What's the problem here?

Note that I'm forced to use C++98 standard and cannot use `#include <sys/stat.h>` or `#include <unistd.h>` as suggested in the accepted answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c)

Comment: If possible, learn C++11; C+98 is really obsolete. And read documentation of [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) carefully. Post also some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your shown code probably don't behave as you say

Comment: Did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297560/4143855) not help? `std::fstream ifile(filename.c_str(), ios_base::out | ios_base::in);`

Comment: Not reproducible https://ideone.com/Z4c2EW

Comment: To what purpose do you want to do this? In general, I try to avoid "checking if a file exists" etc, because of the "Time Of Check To Time of Use" problems that this creates.

Comment: See my discussion on the subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818099/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-before-creating-a-new-file

Answer (score 9):

You can use either of these functions to see if a file exists

```
bool DoesFileExist (const std::string& name) {
    ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}
```

or

```
bool DoesFileExist (const std::string& name) {
    if (FILE *file = fopen(name.c_str(), "r")) {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

or

```
bool DoesFileExist (const std::string& name) {
    return ( access( name.c_str(), F_OK ) != -1 );
}
```

or

```
bool DoesFileExist (const std::string& name) {
  struct stat buffer;   
  return (stat (name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0); 
}
```

Comment: Good for using `fopen()`. Unfortunately, `std::ifstream` may validly _create_ a file.

Comment: About usage of fopen . File may exist, but you may not be able to read it. In this case fopen may not return a valid pointer...